# Why don't I obtain tag instance attached to my question instance?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm beginner in django and new to DRF. So, the problem is within my create() method in my nested serializer. The thing is that it creates new tags instances but don't attach them to question instance which I'd like to send on server in my POST request.

Here is my model:

```
class Question(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    content = models.CharField(max_length=500, default="Write your question")  # HTMLField() look  TinyMCE
    tags = models.ManyToManyField("Tag")
    pub_date = models.DateField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    answers = models.ManyToManyField("Answer")
    comment_cnt = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    like_cnt = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('questions', args=[self.title])

    class Meta:    
        ordering = ['pub_date']

class Answer(models.Model):
    content = models.CharField(max_length=500, default="Write the answer")  # HTMLField() look  TinyMCE
    pub_date = models.DateField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    like_cnt = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.author.username

class Tag(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    discription = models.CharField(max_length=500, default="This is description")
    use_cnt = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Here is serializer:

```
class TagSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Tag
        fields = '__all__' 
        read_only_fields = ['use_cnt']

class AnswerSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Answer
        fields = '__all__' 

class QuestionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    tags = TagSerializer(many=True )
    answers = AnswerSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Question
        fields = '__all__' 

    def create(self, validated_data):
        tags_data = validated_data.pop('tags')
        question = Question.objects.create(**validated_data)
        for tag_data in tags_data:
            Tag.objects.create(question=question, **tag_data)
        return question
```

Here is my view:

```
class QuestionList(mixins.ListModelMixin,
                   mixins.CreateModelMixin,
                   generics.GenericAPIView):

    queryset = Question.objects.all()
    serializer_class = QuestionSerializer
    # permission_classes = [AllowAny]

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.list(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.create(request, *args, **kwargs)

class QuestionDetail(mixins.RetrieveModelMixin,
                     mixins.UpdateModelMixin,
                     mixins.DestroyModelMixin,
                     generics.GenericAPIView):

    queryset = Question.objects.all()
    serializer_class = QuestionSerializer
    # permission_classes = [IsOwnerOrReadOnly]
    lookup_field = 'title'

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.retrieve(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def put(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.update(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def delete(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.destroy(request, *args, **kwargs)

class TagList(mixins.ListModelMixin,
              mixins.CreateModelMixin,
              generics.GenericAPIView):

    queryset = Tag.objects.all()
    serializer_class = TagSerializer
    # permission_classes = [AllowAny]

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.list(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.create(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

I am sending this in my POST request:

```
{
"tags": [{
    "name": "new tag",
    "discription": "description"
},
{
    "name": "another tag",
    "discription": "description"
}],
"title": "new one",
"content": "new content",
"comment_cnt": 2,
"like_cnt": 2,
"author": 2
}
```

and receiving this:

```
"id": 14,
"tags": [],
"answers": [],
"title": "new one",
"content": "new content",
"pub_date": "2019-07-26",
"comment_cnt": 2,
"like_cnt": 2,
"author": 2
```

and tags separately:

```
{
    "id": 9,
    "name": "new tag",
    "discription": "description",
    "use_cnt": 0
},
{
    "id": 10,
    "name": "another tag",
    "discription": "description",
    "use_cnt": 0
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Your Tag model does not have `question`, so it wont work as you'd expect.

Try to do this instead:

```
   def create(self, validated_data):
        tags_data = validated_data.pop('tags')
        question = Question.objects.create(**validated_data)
        for tag_data in tags_data:
            tag = Tag.objects.create(**tag_data)
            question.tags.add(tag)

        question.save()

        return question
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag)
```

Also

```
for tag_data in tags_data:
        tag = Tag.objects.create(**tag_data)
        question.tags.add(tag)
question.save()
```

Comment: You can not use assignment in ManyToMany relation as question=question while creating object. You can do similar thing in ForeignKey, but not in many-to-many. You should add